# How to handle internal server error in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I send an Ajax request in JavaScript (with JQuery), it sometimes throws an internal server error that I can't catch. The error shows up in the browser. I even tried to wrap the ajax call in a try - catch block. How can I handle the Ajax error?

**EDIT**
here is my code:

```
$.post('/multi/getGameStatus', function(data) {
    if(data && data.game) {
        settings.game = data.game;
        setStartRacePopupUI.call(this, data);
        // remove all racers
        removePlayers.call();
        for(var i=0;i<settings.game.players.length;i++) {
            var player = settings.game.players[i];
            var isme = (player.id == settings.playerId);
            addPlayer.call(this, player, isme, i);
        }

        if (settings.game.gameStatus == "OPEN") {
            setTimeout(refreshPlayers, refreshPlayersInterval, nextStatus);
        } else if(settings.game.gameStatus == "IN_GAME") {
            counterToGameStart = data.sts;
            gameFllow(nextStatus);
        }
    }
});
```

Even if I use the error handler I still get a JS error on the page

Comment: can you provide some code example? where do you see that error? do your entire page get replaced by a 500 error page or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> ...For convenience and consistency with the callback names used by
>   $.ajax(), jqXHR also provides .error(), .success(), and .complete()
>   methods.
>
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks
>   will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their
>   eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always()
>   instead.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"myurl",
  data: {json:"data"},
  success: function(){//on success},
  error: function(){//called on error}
});
```

error callback as per [ajax api docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): (when in doubt refer to api docs)

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)Function
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
> three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
> string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
> exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
> argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
> "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
> textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
> Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
> of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
> is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
> Ajax Event.